# Image is not detected if taken from camera Using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am taking Images from The camera(Making use of `UIImagePickerController`) and saving it to the document directory.

Then i fetch these images in a different view controller to get the face part, using `CIDetector API` and `CIfacefeature API`.

The problem is It is not detecting the face at all though i am able to fetch the images properly. And if i store the same image in the main bundle it detects.

I do not know where the problem is??. I have tried everything. May Be the problem is with the `UIImage` or may be the format in which image is getting saved in document directory or with the camera.

Please help. I will be grateful to you.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                      [NSString stringWithString: @"SampleImage.jpg"] ];
    NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    [picker  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    FCVC *fcvc = [[FCVC alloc] initwithImage:image];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fcvc animated:YES];
}
```

In the ViewDidLoad of FCVC I am calling below function by passing :

```
-(void)markFaces:(UIImage *)pic 
{
    CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:pic.CGImage];
    CGImageRef masterFaceImage;

    CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType: CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

// create an array containing all the detected faces from the detector    
   NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];
   for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
   {       
        masterFaceImage  =  CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(facePicture.CGImage,CGRectMake(faceFeature.bounds.origin.x,faceFeature.bounds.origin.y, faceFeature.bounds.size.width,faceFeature.bounds.size.height));
   }
   self.masterExtractedFace = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masterFaceImage];
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix for this, if you're using the camera always in portrait, is to add this little snippet:

```
NSDictionary* imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6] forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];
NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image options:imageOptions];
```

To figure out what orientation you're in if you need it to dynamically figure out your orientation.

check `kCGImagePropertyOrientation`

Comment: how can i detect the image in LandScapeMode

Comment: check kCGImagePropertyOrientation